# Elevating markers on google street view

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-street-view

I want to place markers high above ground. to explain in detail, i want the marker placed to look like its in the air, or for example on 8th floor of a building. google maps api only gives me lat and lng controls, which just moves the marker around x and y axis, I want to move them by z axis as well.

this is basic marker code:

`const bankMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: { lat: 40.729681, lng: -73.991138 }, map, icon: "https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=dollar|FFFF00", title: "Bank", });`

https://jsfiddle.net/re1thcwf/23/ - this is a playground for google street view api.

One solution i have come up with is to do overlays and move the items in accordance to user input but it would be a big headache to come up with correct formulas and track user input/toggle/scroll.

Comment: As you have mentioned, there's no feature at the moment that would allow you to do that. I suggest you file a Feature Request. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker